# Generating DLL in visual studio

Tags: c++, dll, linkageerror

i am trying to generate dll file, use its .lib file in another program ,but unfortunately, no .lib file is generated!
what should i do?

Comment: this is the error i get:
linkage specification is incompatible with previous "add" (declared at line 1)

Comment: Find out everything you need to get started by taking the tour[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)if you need to help

Comment: If you don't get a .lib then the most likely mishap is that you forgot to export anything.  Use __declspec(dllexport) or a .def file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
extern "C" _declspec (dllexport) int add(int a, int b);

extern "C" _declspec (dllexport) int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but actually i need .lib file but its not generated!

Comment: so edit your question and make what you want clearer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `__declspec` (two underscores) with `dllexport` attribute to export a symbol from a DLL. And on client side you'll need to use `__declspec(dllimport)`.

You better put the declaration on header like this:

```
// YourHeader.H
#ifdef _DLL_EXPORTING // Define this symbol in DLL project setting
#define EXPORT_IMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

EXPORT_IMPORT int add(int,int);
```

Let the client use this header directly without worrying about `declspec` specifier. The `EXPORT_IMPORT` macro can also be used to export any other functions you want to export/import.